# Creating jobs in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have created a database in SQL Server 2008 and I have assigned a job to it which get backup from my database once a day.

Now I want to attach my database to SQL Server in another system.

Should I create the job again on the second server or it has been transferred with mdf file itself?

Answer (score 1):

Jobs are stored in the MSDB database, not as part of the MDF for any user database. You will have to script the job from the old server and/or create the job again on your new server.

Answer (score 0):

In the object explorer, expand 'SQL Server Agent' and expand 'Jobs'. You can see for yourself if the job is there or not.

If you can't see the Object Explorer, go to View --> Object Explorer